# Building a node docker image results in error 133

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm building a remix.run project with Docker in a raspberry.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

But when I build it I get the following error:

```
$ docker image build -t website .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.398MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> de31857d30b5
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b3558d128e4
Step 3/7 : COPY ./package*.json /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1d5f47f3a87
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 279c78d7a2b3


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# unreachable code
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7eb164ec
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 133
```

A little of online research gave me the idea that I could running out of memory, but I don't think this is the case

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          923Mi       149Mi       282Mi       7.0Mi       491Mi       712Mi
Swap:          99Mi          0B        99Mi
```

I also tried to build the image with `RUN npm install --verbose` but nothing changed in the output

Comment: Same for me tbh, not sure what I am doing wrong.
Let me know if you find anything. Thanks!

Comment: @volk I used a different image, like `node:debian` and seems to works, try it and let me know

Comment: I patched `libseccomp` manually as I described in the answer to the thread. But I guess using `node:debian` would be much simpler solution.
Thanks for pinging me here, and sorry for not coming back to this question - has been lost in numerous opened tabs

Comment: actually I was to quick to judge, also I managed to run docker image with node command npm i is failing with the same error no matter what.
When I debugged it initially i removed `npm i` for debugging purposes
@Nullndr let me know if npm i works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a solution to this one.

After some debugging I found the root cause in this thread: https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt/issues/7662#issuecomment-852985841

Basically the issue is with the `libseccomp` package not being updated for debian based distributives.
That's why docker build failed on 1st `node` or `npm` command it encountered.
After following instructions in that comment and updating `libseccomp` manually I managed to get everything up and running.

But just using `node:debian` as suggested by @Nullndr in the comments to initial question might be much easier indeed =)